# How to add cell to UITableView of next controller on click of button on first ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am scanning an image(specially visit card) using OCR. I get all content of this image in array e.g. Name, Adress, Phone number, email id. So, after click on button I should get all this information of card get saved on second ViewControllers UITableView Permanently. So when I scan an another card, this cards info (cell) also should append on first cards data i.e. add all cards data cell by cell. Please guide me as early as possible.

Comment: Create an array with all your cards in your first VC. Every time you add another card call `[tableView reloadData];` that should refresh your first VC. Now when you click the button, you pass the new array to the second VC.

Comment: what to do to save previous data

Comment: Keep an array with your cards as a property of your VC.

Comment: Please share some code how you store your cards and what happens when you click the button. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask